# how to remove Cloth Rustling?

Tags: noise, microphone, reduction, lapel

i have recorded some interviews using lapel microphones and it has a lot of rustling noise because the characters have been moving. i have tried editing it out and to some extent it has worked. but there are some parts where the rustling overlaps with the dialogue. Is there any way i can remove or minimize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for RX and the decrackle module. Select the whole clip then go nuts and set the strength to the maximum. Check how much it can achieve before undoing and working on it in the specific parts. Work in spectral view and whatever you can't decrackle, try using spectral repair (I usually use the attenuate mode). Take a lot of trail and error all-in-all but you'll get something decent.

RX combined with good editing will yield some darn good results.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for iZotope RX.  Using denoise with an isolated cloth rustle as a noiseprint to learn you might be able to lower the cloth sounds but I doubt you would be able to remove them entirely without affecting the voice dramatically.

Comment: [Adobe Audition](http://www.adobe.com/nl/products/audition.html) (Previously Cool Edit Pro) also has this feature. First analyze a spot with only the rustling (no voice), then tweak the parameters to get the best compromise between rustle and denoizer-artifacts / distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Izotope denoise can help but I've had better luck with the declick or decrackle modules, depending on the length, spectral repair can be even better but takes more time.  Cloth rustle can appear in many different forms and vary a lot depending on where the mic was placed and type of cloth.

Answer (score 1):

If you record dialog in the field, the audio you record should be clean, and flawless, and the dialog crisp and intelligible, under all possible conditions, including the vacuum of space.

No, it isn't easy to uphold this ideal. But it is the demarcation between sound captured by a professional, vs. a non-professional.

In my book, which is a bit different than some - I always assume post-processing software and DSP does not exist. If I can't get a take with a microphone, amplifier, recorder, and a few simple accessories - no one will save me or my job. There is no button with "fix-it-in-post" written beneath. I've never seen one. Nothing that can be solved in the field with hardware or technique should ever, ever be solved with software in post, especially when it comes to removing noise from dialog. The human voice is important. When you de-noise audio of human voices, the algorithms used often are destructive processes from which no recording can recover its original timbre, nuance, quality.

Post software should be used as a last resort.

My suggestion is to invest in a class (they're all online now!) or spend several hours on Vimeo or Youtube educating yourself on lavalier placement and techniques - there is a surprising amount of finesse and skill that goes into placing a lav.

Once you have the basics, then consider investing in some quality lav accessories, like lav concealers, clips, tapes - pretty much everything you need to get rid of (or get just the right amount) of rustle exists already. You can hold it in your hands. Bubblebee Industries has a good brand-agnostic line of lav placement kits, foams, problem solvers, etc., to solve these exact types of problems in the field before you destroy your audio, and subsequently your credibility. They may be worth looking into - but not before committing to just a few hours of education on the basic elements of how soundwork is done.

Answer (score 0):

With RX 5 Audio Editor if you're working in Pro Tools or similar you can use Connect to roundtrip a clip to the audio editor standalone application, this works great - I found just now that with clothing rustle in my dialog it was a combination of using de-noise on selective frequencies and then just good old EQ to take the noise down even further. I couldn't completely obliterate my clothing noise but I was able to reduce it to acceptable levels.